# Append DIV with link style

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have hundreds of HTML pages and I would like to add a new div with link and style to them but editing each page takes lots of time.

All the pages have one common JavaScript file.

how can I append or add below div to all the pages?

```
<div  style="background-color:#561D1B;" id="testid">
    <marquee style="background-color:#561D1B;height:19px;"><script src="https://testurl.com/test" type="text/javascript" ></script></marquee>
    </div>
```

avoid-fout is a class and I tried to add below code but it's not working.

```
$(".avoid-fout").append("<div  style="background-color:#561D1B;" id="testid">
    <marquee style="background-color:#561D1B;height:19px;"><script src="https://testurl.com/test" type="text/javascript" ></script></marquee>
    </div>");
```

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/append/

Comment: i tried but its not working...see my question

Comment: Is your script src actually a valid js ???

Answer (score 1):

When appending, make sure you observe the use of single and double quotes, as shown below

```
$(".avoid-fout").append('<div style="background-color:#561D1B;" id="testid">
<marquee style="background-color:#561D1B;height:19px;"><script src="https://testurl.com/test" type="text/javascript" ></script></marquee>
</div>');
```

Use single quote first, then everything inside should be done with double quotes, or vice versa.

Comment: its not  working console says Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$(".avoid-fout").append(`<div style="background-color:#561D1B;" id="testid"> <marquee style="background-color:#561D1B;height:19px;"><script src="https://testurl.com/test" type="text/javascript" ></script></marquee>
</div>`);
```

Also make sure, your script src is a valid JS

Answer (score 0):

Your `.append` call will not work because you are appending a string with double quotes, and also using double-quotes in the html. Simplest fix is to use single quotes for your html string instead:

```
$(".avoid-fout").append('<div  style="background-color:#561D1B;" id="testid">
<marquee style="background-color:#561D1B;height:19px;"><script src="https://testurl.com/test" type="text/javascript" ></script></marquee>
</div>');`
```

Comment: its not  working console says Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

Comment: It is because the string spans multiple lines, single and double quoted strings in JS can not include new lines ([unless](https://jack.ofspades.com/multiline-strings-in-es6-javascript/index.html) you escape them with a backslash, but that can be error-prone and not a lot of people know about it.). I'd either just join it into one line, or if feasible in your target environments, use a [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) instead of a single or double quoted string.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to use Jquery or avoid inserting HTML string, this might help. It uses vanilla JS dom APIs. You can modify the method `appendToElem` in case you need to add any other stuff

```js
        function appendToElem(elem) {
            if (!elem) {
                console.error(elem)
            }
            var script = document.createElement('script')
            script.setAttribute("src", "https://testurl.com/test")
            script.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript")

            var marquee = document.createElement('marquee')
            marquee.style.backgroundColor = "#561D1B"
            marquee.style.height = "19px"
            marquee.appendChild(script)

            var div = document.createElement("div")
            div.id = "testid"
            div.style.backgroundColor = "#561D1B"
            div.appendChild(marquee)

            elem.appendChild(div)
        }
        appendToElem(document.getElementsByClassName('avoid-fout')[1])
```

```html
    <div class="avoid-fout">
        <h2>Some Random title</h2>
        <p>Some Text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="avoid-fout">
        <h2>Add At the end of this container</h2>
        <p>
            Add the asked div, with marquee and script below this. 
        </p>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of problems.  You are trying to use double-quotes inside of a double quoted string, you can't do that without [escaping](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#Escape_notation) the double quotes.

```
"This is "not" a valid string";
"This \"is\" a valid string";
```

A simple solution to this that I usually use is to just use single quotes to encapsulate HTML and only use double-quotes in my HTML:

```
'<div id="double-quotes-work-here">Just can\'t use unescaped single-quotes</div>';
```

The other problem is that you are trying to use a string that spans multiple lines. Single and double quoted strings in JS can generally not include any new line characters. In cases like this where you are just inserting HTML and the new lines don't actually matter, the easiest thing to do would be to just delete the new lines and include all the HTML on one line:

```js
$(".avoid-fout").append('<div  style="background-color:#561D1B;" id="testid"> <marquee style="background-color:#561D1B;height:19px;">Foo</marquee> </div>');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="avoid-fout"></div>
```

If you want to keep it on multiple lines, there are [a few options](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#Long_literal_strings).

You could use multiple concatenated strings:

```js
$(".avoid-fout").append('<div  style="background-color:#561D1B;" id="testid">' +
'<marquee style="background-color:#561D1B;height:19px;">Foo</marquee>' +
'</div>');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="avoid-fout"></div>
```

Or you could escape the new-lines by using `\`:

```js
$(".avoid-fout").append('<div  style="background-color:#561D1B;" id="testid">\
<marquee style="background-color:#561D1B;height:19px;">Foo</marquee>\
</div>');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="avoid-fout"></div>
```

This way should be avoided though. It is fairly error-prone, if there is any white space after the `\`, it will cause a syntax error; one that is really hard to notice since the white space is not visible. For instance:

```
'this is a valid\
multi-line string';

'this is not a valid\ 
multi-line string';
```

See the difference? Me neither.

If the browsers you are targeting all support it ([most modern browser do](https://caniuse.com/#feat=template-literals)), I would use a [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals):

```js
$(".avoid-fout").append(`<div  style="background-color:#561D1B;" id="testid">
<marquee style="background-color:#561D1B;height:19px;">Foo</marquee>
</div>`);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="avoid-fout"></div>
```

Template literals allow you to use multi-line strings without any escaping, you can use both single and double quotes inside of them without escaping them. They also allow you to do other neat things like [expression interpolation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#Expression_interpolation) and using [tagged templates](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#Tagged_templates).

Learning to use the [developer console](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_are_browser_developer_tools) in your browser, as well as a linter, such as [jsHint](http://jshint.com/) can help a lot with spotting errors like these.